# CouchDB gives no_majority when trying to update _security

Tags: couchdb

After couchdb upgrade it was no longer possible to create new databases or update _security of old databases.

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into this with CouchDB 2.1.1. My problem was that the security object I was attempting to pass in was malformed.

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2326,

> Attempts to write security objects where the "admins" or "members" values are malformed will result in an HTTP 500 response with the following body:

```js
{"error":"error","reason":"no_majority"}
```

> This should really be an HTTP 400 response with a "bad_request" error value and a different error reason.
>
> To reproduce:

```sh
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:15984/test
{"ok":true}
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:15984/test/_security -d '{"admins":[]}'
{"error":"error","reason":"no_majority"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another reason could be that old nodes were lingering in _membership configuration.

I.e., _membership showed:

```
{
    "all_nodes": [
        "couchdb@localhost"
    ],
    "cluster_nodes": [
        "couchdb@127.0.0.1",
        "couchdb@localhost"
    ]
}
```

when it should show

```
{
    "all_nodes": [
        "couchdb@localhost"
    ],
    "cluster_nodes": [
        "couchdb@localhost"
    ]
}
```

Doing a deletion of the bad cluster node as described in [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/cluster/nodes.html#removing-a-node) helped.

Note, that _nodes might not be available on port 5984, but on 5986 only.

Comment: This worked and the hint that `_nodes` is only available on port 5986 was gold, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, it was lonely in here ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a PUT to /db/_security, if the user is not a a db or server admin, the response is HTTP status 500 with {"error":"error","reason":"no_majority"} but the server logs are more informative, including: {forbidden,<<"You are not a db or server admin.">>}

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be couchdb process reached its maximum number of open files, which lead to read errors and (wrongly) no_majority errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be that the server switched from single node configuration to multiple node configuration (for example during an upgrade).

Changing back number of nodes to 1 helped